# How to control page width by buttons

Tags: javascript

I wanna know how to have buttons to control the page width like this:
https://startbootstrap.com/previews/scrolling-nav .

Screenshot: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/10388675?key=a9873d3579b85f169baebd01ea24a59f

In the past, I've tried putting the content into a div and use JavaScript to adjust the div width. The problem is that it'll get more complicated when there are many div because you need to target the different buttons ( which controlling the width ) to the respective div, and the styling will need to rewrite on JavaScript again since it's the div changing its width and that' why it won't trigger the CSS media queries.

So is anyone know how to achieve this result where I can have several buttons that can control the page width while making sure it targets the right div and trigger the CSS media queries so I won't have to repeat the styling in JavaScript?

Comment: where is the buttons in your link?

Comment: @HosMercury I've updated my question with a screenshot, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Future Solution

---

There as of now, is no great way to do what you are looking for with CSS media queries. There is however, a current proposal for something called [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries). According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=container%20queries), Chrome Canary has an early version that

> Can be enabled with the "Enable CSS Container Queries" feature flag
> under `chrome://flags`

but, at this point in time (07/07/2021) there is essentially zero support or implementation of this proposal in any browser.

## Current Solution

---

One alternative to this, and what the website you linked above did was embed a page in an `<iframe>` That `<iframe>` can then be resized with JavaScript and the embedded page will respond to media queries.

```js
function resizePage() {
  document.querySelector("iframe").style.width = "600px";
}
```

```css
html,
body,
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="resizePage()">Resize Page</button>
<iframe src="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/"></iframe>
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you so much